# Chaincode Event Payload - Hyperledger Fabric SDK v1.4.1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using Hyperledger Fabric SDK NodeJS v1.4.1 and I'm trying to catch up a chaincode event.
Here my code:

```
let gateway = new Gateway();
await gateway.connect(config, {
    wallet: wallet, 
    identity: identity, 
    discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false },
});
let network = await gateway.getNetwork("myChannel");
let contract = network.getContract("myChaincode");

contract.addContractListener("myListener","myChaincodeEvent",(err, event, blockNumber, transactionId, status) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    logger.debug(`Chaincode:${event.chaincode_id} - Event: ${event.event_name} - Block Number: ${blockNumber} Transaction ID: ${transactionId} Status: ${status}`);

},{unregister:false,disconnect:false});
```

My issue is that I'm receiving the event but I'm not able to retrieve the payload from it.

I read that is necessary to set the option in the channel hub:

> full_block=true

but I don't understand where to set this parameter if I use the gateway approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the code I used showing where to set the appropriate filtered option

```
    this.contract.addContractListener('some-string', 'trade-network',
        (err, event, blkNum, txid, status) => {
            console.log('event received', status, event, blkNum, txid);
            if (err) {
                this.emit('error', err);
            } else if (status && status === 'VALID') {
                // only if a valid block is committed should we emit an event
                let evt = event.payload.toString('utf8');
                evt = JSON.parse(evt);
                if (Array.isArray(evt)) {
                    for(const oneEvent of evt) {
                        this.emit('ChaincodeEvent', oneEvent);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this.emit('ChaincodeEvent', evt);
                }
            }
       },
       {filtered: false}
    );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: By any chance. Do you have any example using all possible listener options? Putting a startBlock does not change anything (it still starts on the newest one) even though the doc says it can be used.

Comment: I don't sorry, I've not tried it. Would suggest raising a JIRA if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options to ChannelEventHub.connect(options)

like this

```
channelEventHub.connect({ full_block: true })
```

check the API document
https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/ChannelEventHub.html